# Change swap size after upgrade

Tags: 12.10, swap

I have just upgraded my cpu/mobo/RAM and I would like to now increase the swap size without having to reformat my entire drive.   Is this possible? My hard drive set up is as follows.

```
mount 
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro) 
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw) 
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw) 
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw) 
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755) 
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620) 
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755) 
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880) 
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev) 
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw) 
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/raph/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=raph)
```

sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 200.0 GB, 200049647616 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24321 cylinders, total 390721968 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x0007f9dc

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   390721535   195109889    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   390721535   195109888   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root: 198.8 GB, 198784843776 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 24167 cylinders, total 388251648 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1: 1006 MB, 1006632960 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 122 cylinders, total 1966080 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up your data before you do follow the steps below. This usually works without any issues but that doesn't account for bugs, power failures, etc.

1. Use `e2resize` to shrink the root logical volume (`/dev/mapper/ubuntu-root`) first.
2. Then use `lvresize` to  shrink the logical volume to the size of the filesystem you just shrunk.
3. Now when you use `vgdisplay`, you'll notice there's some free space (extents) in that volume group.
4. Temporarily disable your swap with `swapoff -a`
5. You can use `lvextend` to expand `/dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1` by with the extents you've just gained from shrinking the root LV.
6. Create and re-enable your swap with `mkswap /dev/mapper/ubuntu-swap_1 && swapon -a`

Comment: Should I be doing this from a live cd/usb stick?

Comment: You can but you don't need to. You don't even need to reboot your machine to do this.

Comment: Just a small thing but e2resize doesn't seem to exist for 12.10.  Do you mean resize2fs ?

Answer (score 0):

How to change swap size on Ubuntu 18.04 this takes about 10 minutes (no reboot required):

```
sudo swapoff -a

# For 16GB of swap size
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=16

sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

To check the swap file:

```
grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
sudo swapon --show
free -m
```